# TKInter Can't change value of stringvar

Tags: python, tkinter

I have this python 2.7.9 code. The error lies in the `chooseKid()` function. The StringVar `current` and Label `chosenKid` don't update. I have verified that the `chooseKid()` does run, and `choice` variable is set. However `chosenKid`

```
from Tkinter import Tk,Button,StringVar,Entry,Label
import random

root= Tk()

current=StringVar()
kids=[]

addKidName=Entry(root)
def addkid():
    kids.append(addKidName.get())
    print kids
addKid=Button(root, text="Add a student", command=addkid)


def choosekid():
    chosen=random.choice(kids)
    current.set(chosen)
chooseKid=Button(root,text="Pick random student", command=choosekid)
chosenKid=Label(root,text=current)


addKid.grid(row=0,column=1)
addKidName.grid(row=0,column=0)
chooseKid.grid(row=1,column=1)
chosenKid.grid(row=1,column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You could use the .set() command??? I dunno if that was helpful but just putting that out there. textVariableName.set("new Value")

Comment: @PamalMangat - That is already in the current code, in the noted function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set a `textvariable`, not `text`. This will allow the `Label` contents to match whatever is currently in the `StringVar`.

```
chosenKid=Label(root, textvariable=current)
```